# Клонирование удалённого репозитория в удалённый

Tags: git, bitbucket

Есть склонированный удалённый репозиторий Х

Хочу создать точную копию этого репозитория, не склонировать на компьютер, а так же, удалённый на битбакете.

Что сделано

```
git clone
git remote set-url origin <Адрес второго пустого репозитория>
git push
```

Вроде залилось всё, но размер нового репозитория примерно на 20% меньше чем старого.

Я что то сделал не так? Есть ли способ копировать удалённый репозитории проще и удобнее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Я что то сделал не так?

если хэш последнего коммита в каждой ветке совпадает, то «всё так».

> Есть ли способ копировать удалённый репозитории проще и удобнее?

можно сократить на одну команду:

```
$ git clone адрес-старого-хранилища .
$ git push --all адрес-нового-хранилища
```

хотя для локальной работы с обоими удалёнными хранилищами удобнее зарегистрировать оба:

```
$ git clone адрес-старого-хранилища .
$ git remote add имя-нового-хранилища адрес-нового-хранилища
$ git push --all имя-нового-хранилища
```

> не склонировать на компьютер

а иначе не получится: «хранилища git размножаются клонированием».